# How do I loop over a HashMap after retrieving Firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working in Android Studio, and retrieving the following data from Firebase:

```
coloursets:
   default:
      name: "Default colour set"
      description: "Default set of colours"
      colours:
          white:
             red: 255
             green: 255
             blue: 255
             name: "white"
          black:
             red: 0
             green: 0
             blue: 0
             name: "black"
```

I'm retrieving it like this:

```
public void initialiseColourSet(ValueEventListener listener) {

    if(this.key == null) return;

DatabaseReference mColourSetReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("coloursets").child(this.key);

mColourSetReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

where "key" is set to "default", and "listener" is:

```
new ValueEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       ArrayList<ChartColour> colourList= new ArrayList<>();
       Map<String, HashMap> objectMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

       // SOMETHING NEEDS TO GO HERE - SEE BELOW

       }

}
```

The ColourSet class has the following:

```
String key, name, description;
ArrayList<ChartColour> colours = new ArrayList<>();
```

So, I want to loop over 'objectMap' to get the colourSet name and description, and then get the list of colours into the local variable colourList, which is then used to set 'colours' in the ColourSet object.

I just can't get the loop correct in listener.  I've looked up lots of answers, but none seem to quite apply to my case.

Currently I have the following in listener:

```
new ValueEventListener() {

   @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<ChartColour> colourList= new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, HashMap> objectMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
     for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap> entry : objectMap.entrySet()) {
       switch (entry.getKey()) {
         case "name":
           mColourSet.setName(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
           break;
         case "description":
           mColourSet.setDescription(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
           break;
         case "colours":
           // Need some kind of FOR LOOP here
             ChartColour colour = new ChartColour();
             /*
                colour.setKey(??);
                colour.setName(??);
                colour.setRed(??);
                   ... etc ... */
                colourList.add(colour);
           // END OF FOR LOOP
           mColourSet.setColours(colourList);
       }
     }
   }
});
```

So, I'm just not sure what I need to put in the FOR loop in the listener, in order to loop over the colours. Everything I've tried so far just gives me the wiggly red line, without any explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure where your squiggly red lines are, but your `HashMap`s as the value type of the outer map don't have the generic types set, which means the key and value both resolve to `Object`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean for objectMap?  What should they be set to?

Comment: I mean in `Map<String, HashMap>`, the `HashMap` part does not specify the type parameters, so it is effectively `HashMap<Object, Object>`. I imagine it would need to be `HashMap<String, String>` in this case. That could easily contribute to some squiggly red lines in your code, but without knowing where the errors are I cannot be sure. I haven't tried to run you code yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a bit of time to look at your code, and I have noticed a few things that seem off.

First, when I try to implement `ValueEventListener`, there is another method that is required to be implemented. Perhaps there is some difference in code version, but that may be one point that is trivial to fix.

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
```

Second, your type cast for the return value of `dataSnapshot.getValue()` cannot be correct. The sample data does not match with the notion that the data is `Map<String, HashMap>`. The "name" and "description" entries are clearly simple `String`s, not `HashMap`s. I would imagine that fails at runtime. It is more likely that you should be casting to `Map<String, ?>`. From that point, you will have to inform the code what is expected of each entry value, which will variably be a `String` or `Map` or `Integer` depending upon which key. If I had to hazard a guess at what your `onDataChange` method should look like (informed by your sample data), it would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, ?> defaultColourSet = (Map<String, ?>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
    if (defaultColourSet == null) {
        /* log a warning, DataSnapshot.getValue may return null */
        return;
    }
    List<ChartColour> colourList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> colorSetEntry : defaultColourSet.entrySet()) {
        switch (colorSetEntry.getKey()) {
            case "name":
                mColourSet.setName((String)colorSetEntry.getValue());
                break;
            case "description":
                mColourSet.setDescription((String)colorSetEntry.getValue());
                break;
            case "colours":
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, ?> colourMap = (HashMap<String, ?>)colorSetEntry.getValue();
                for (Map.Entry<String, ?> colourEntry : colourMap.entrySet()) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String, ?> colourValueMap = (Map<String, ?>)colourEntry.getValue();
                    ChartColour colour = new ChartColour();
                    // Note that the following calls are based on assumption...
                    colour.setName((String)colourValueMap.get("name"));
                    colour.setRed((Integer)colourValueMap.get("red"));
                    colour.setGreen((Integer)colourValueMap.get("green"));
                    colour.setBlue((Integer)colourValueMap.get("blue"));
                    colourList.add(colour);
                }
                mColourSet.setColours(colourList);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` in places where unchecked casts occur to indicate that the cast is safe based on knowledge that is unavailable to the compiler. It is strictly informed by the layout of your JSON data. It can potentially fail at runtime, particularly if the data ever changes. I would recommend adding more robust error handling, like a try-catch to handle `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have OnCancelled, just didn't put it in here to save space - apologies, I should have made that clear.

Comment: I'll check out the rest and see how I get on. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you! This made things so much clearer. I didn't realise that I could put a ? in the Map definition - I was trying to use HashMap and then cast to what I needed, which obviously wasn't working. I'll work on the error handling now - just wanted to get things working first.  Thanks again for your help!